# jqplot - how to make 2 lines to scale same base

Tags: jqplot

lets say i have 2 sets of data:

1) 10 11 15 20
2) 1000 1200 1400 1500

now i wanna make them start in same point (like they were converted to same base %)

so:
1) 10 11 15 20
2) 10 12 14 15
i can do it in php BUT then value in hover box is wrong...

so to sum up - i wanna make 2 lines starting from exactly same point (like they were scaled to the base) but on hover or markers to show REAL numbers on both (idea is to compare growth of data A vs data B - which one did better in % values, not absolute)

thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i think i found a so so solution:

i hide actual value of the second set, add extra data set (now its [date,value(scaled to base value of first line),real_value(the one i want to show on tooltip)].

but problem is - when you wanna use tooltip it always include 2nd value from dataset (in my case scaled valued), so i guess only solution is to make it invisible in css x.x.

marking as answered - its good enough and cant find anything better